# Why doesnt one div not show, but another does

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a website for my Minecraft server and I'm attempting to put a background behind a couple of lines of text I wrote. I am having trouble where my `div` isn't showing. I didn't type the `div` id correctly at first, but now it's still not showing, but when I do type id correctly it changes the height and width of my webpage.... How come?

```css
#happy {
  color: green;
  position: relative;
  top: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px;
  left: 500px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#para {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  top: 265px;
  left: 350px;
  color: black;
```

```html
<div id="happy">
  <p id="para">
    Welcome to Skycraft. This is a white-listed vanilla server that was created by GamingMashup and includes yooutubers such as <br> TimelySeekerYT, The Blob army, Bluddynoodle, CraftingGamerMC
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Please include _all_ of your HTML + CSS. If something isn't appearing, it's generally because the element directly above it is _invalid_ HTML or overlapping in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#happy {
  color: green;
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100px; 
  z-index: 1;
}

#para {
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative; 
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="happy">
  <p id="para">Welcome to Skycraft. This is a white-listed vanilla server that was created
    by GamingMashup and includes yooutubers such as <br>TimelySeekerYT, The Blob army, Bluddynoodle,
    CraftingGamerMC<br></p>
</div>
```

I have removed the following from your code:

```
#happy {   
   top: 500px;  
   left: 500px;
}

#para {  
   top: 265px;
   left: 350px;
}
```

The reason being.. `top` and `left` set the position of your elements for instance `top: 500px` sets it as roughly `500px` from the top. You defined `#happy` to have a height of `300px` therefore the `happy` div will site `200px` below this, thus being invisible.

There are quite a few instances of this, just remove the `top` and `left` tags and it will display correctly. If you want to position it, consider using a different method.

A better definition for `top` is as follows:

> If position: relative; - the top property makes the element's top edge to move above/below its normal position.

From: [CSS top Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_top.asp)

Comment: I wanted to answer that, but not knowing how his website is set, maybe there's a reason his div is set to top&left: 500px; I agree with you though that `#para` being relative to the div shouldn't have top and left positions that high.

Comment: Irrespective, if his positioning is reliant on `top` or `left` with set heights, this is the reason his `div` and `p` aren't showing, therefore answers the question :)